# What's the command to take a picture in Sikuli

Tags: sikuli

I'm using Sikuli IDE.  I'd like to know what the command to take a screenshot is, so I can capture the screen at the end of a test.

Something like this

```python
try :
  if bla bla bla:
    print("blablabla")
  else:
    TAKESCREENSHOT()  #------------------> What command do I put here?
  print("TEST_FAILED")
```

Answer (score 15):

The function is `capture`, as in

```
screen = Screen()
file = screen.capture(screen.getBounds())
print("Saved screen as "+file)
```

It takes a screen-shot, saves it in a file, and gives you the path to that file back.

See the [Sikuli documentation on it](http://doc.sikuli.org/screen.html#capturing) for full details.

Comment: This will launch the manual screen capture screen. If a automated screenshot is needed, you have to provide the coordinates: screen.capture(screen.x, screen.y, screen.w, screen.h)

Comment: @kel thanks for the catch.  Fixed it to be non-interactive whole-screen capture.

Answer (score 4):

Cheap Sikuli trick for screencaps is to have a defined region, then capture the region.

So if you've got a Chrome browser you want to cap, just set it up something like this:

```
App.focus('Chrome.app')

ChromeWindow = App('Chrome.app').window()
```

That will both focus the computer to the target application, and define a region composed of the window parameters of the application. Then run this:

```
capture(ChromeWindow)
```

Then use shutil (`import shutil`) to move the file around to wherever you need it in your local directories. I usually put that code pile into a function I can call when needed `TakePicture(Name)` where `Name` is what I want to call the screencap when called in a particular test. Sikuli is both powerful and easy!

Answer (score 2):

To make a screenshot of the window that has focus you simple can use:

```
focusWindow = App.focusedWindow()
regionImage = capture(focusWindow)
shutil.move(regionImage, os.path.join(r'C:\Screenshots', 'Dummy1.png'))
```