# Is there a way to headlessly screenshot a swing (or awt) window?

Tags: java, swing, awt

There is a legacy app that uses swing, and it spawns various windows for various purposes at various times. What I'm wondering is if it possible to get a "screenshot" of each window, without having to actually go through the screenshot utility on my OS. I know this is *possible* somehow, but I'm wondering if it is something nicely supported by swing/java? I'd love to just load a file via this app, iterate over the windows spawned, and write an image out somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sikuli is pretty neat, it allows you to automate anything, based on image recognition. Their site: [www.sikuli.org](http://www.sikuli.org/). And it can take screenshot while running the automated task you scripted: [How to take screenshot with sikuli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16745722/whats-the-command-to-take-a-picture-in-sikuli)

I'm not affiliate to sikuli whatsoever, I simply used it in the past (to automate tests on a swing GUI). The description on their site:

> Sikuli automates anything you see on the screen. It uses image
>   recognition to identify and control GUI components. It is useful when
>   there is no easy access to a GUI's internal or source code.